# Get Value of dropdown list in jquery entity field

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, entity

I want to get a specific value of drowpdown list using jquery and symfony

my code in formType given as follow

```
 ->add(
            'predefinedMessage',
            'entity',
            array(
                'empty_value' => 'Ajouter un message Prédéfini',
                'class' => 'ACMBundle:Message',
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {

                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.user = :user')
                        ->setParameter('user', $user);

                },

            )
        )
```

the entity Message has many fields: id, name, message, userid

I have a text area in my twig

```
 {{ form_widget(form.message,{ 'attr': {'maxlength': '50','placeholder':'placeholder.message.message'|trans} }) }}
```

in my jquery

```
<script>
$('#add').click(function(){
   var text="{{form.predefinedMessage.vars.data.message }}";
    $('#Pushtype_message').val(text);

});
```

the value of message added to the text area, but when I select the other option, the value in the text area still the same.

consider I have an entity message which contain two line data
id:1 ,userid: 1 , name: message1, message: first message
id:2, userid: 2 , name:message2, message : second message

[image]

Comment: just show your created HTML and javascript that would be enough for answering

Comment: I've added an image to show you the created HTML

Comment: no answar ??????????